# Can Pumpking drop his Trophy before Wave 15?

Tags: terraria-console

I've challenged the Pumpkin Moon about 20 times now. Each time I get to Wave 10 and I have never once gotten Morning Wood or Pumpking trophies. So, can they only drop them during Wave 15?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You just got unlucky.**

There is a 10 % chance for a boss mob to drop a trophy , until the 15th wave of the Pumpkin Moon Event. If it is the 15th wave, if you successfully kill Pumpking, or Mourning Wood you will have a 100 % chance of obtaining the trophy.

**Tips:**

> **1.** Since your going for the trophies, try focusing on hitting the Pumpking and Mourning Wood during the later waves. Don't waste your time anywhere else.
>
> **2.** If your still dying at wave 15, upgrade your gear and try to get the best load-out for your class. Make sure your health is at 500, you have all the required class accessories, and your weapons are the best you can get.

A list of class setups can be found [here](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Class_setups#Ranger_-_Frost).

Comment: AWESOME, +1 for giving class setups

Answer (score 1):

The wiki mentions that the drop is 100% at wave 15, however it has a 10% chance to drop at other times.  So it is quite uncommon, but it can drop before wave 15. [Here is the reference.](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pumpking_Trophy)